# Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"reset", :controller=>"players"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

What do I need to add to config.rb to fix this.

With my very limited knowledge of rails I have managed to put this method in the controller.

```
def  reset
        Player.each do |p|
            p.playing = false
            p.save
        end
   end
```

and create this link in the view

```
<p><%= link_to "New Game", {:action => 'reset' }%></p>
```

I'm just not sure what to put in the routes.rb to get this to work with out stuffing up what I already have.

This is my config.rb

```
ChooseTeams3::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :players
 root :to => "players#index"
get   "/index" => "players#index"


end
```

if I type rake routes I get this

```
    rake routes
    players GET    /players(.:format)          players#index
            POST   /players(.:format)          players#create
 new_player GET    /players/new(.:format)      players#new
edit_player GET    /players/:id/edit(.:format) players#edit
     player GET    /players/:id(.:format)      players#show
            PUT    /players/:id(.:format)      players#update
            DELETE /players/:id(.:format)      players#destroy
       root        /                           players#index
      index GET    /index(.:format)            players#index
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
ChooseTeams3::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :players do
     get "reset", on: :collection
   end
   root :to => "players#index"
   get   "/index" => "players#index"
end
```

For more information about routing, you can read the documentation [here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Update your routes file as..

```
ChooseTeams3::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :players do
     collection do
       get 'reset'
     end
  end
  root :to => "players#index"
  get   "/index" => "players#index"
end
```

and use link_to like this..

```
<p><%= link_to "New Game", reset_players_path%></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ChooseTeams3::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :players do
     get "reset", on: :collection
   end
   root :to => "players#index"
   get   "/index" => "players#index"
end

<p><%= link_to "New Game", reset_players_path %></p>

def  reset
        Player.all.each do |p|
            p.update_attribute(:playing, false)
        end
end
```

but i still why you need, when you click  'New game', update ALL to false.

Player - its a model. if you call Player.all - you will update all Players.

Maybe you need somethin like game.playes.each ( all players for current game )

Comment: I need it because I want players to go and tick off if they are playing. So after a game most players will have playing = true. Then when the next game comes then it needs to reset to playing = false so they can go say if they are playing or not.